# Covert Values to Int

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm creating an Android App that takes data from a ble device. 
I have only a problem, the data that my ble device give to me are like:

> Accelerometer + Gyroscope: "zLAi/wD/SpwiAOv/VwBnAML/xQE="
>
> Pressure: "bgBvAHAAcQByAA="
>
> Battery: "ChYKARoA"

While should have number, how can I convert these values??

For Example I have this function to manageCharacteristics

```
async setupNotifications(device) {
    for (const id in this.AccGyrMg) {

      const service = this.serviceUUID(id)
      const characteristicAccGyrMg = this.notifyUUIDAccGyrMg(id)


      device.monitorCharacteristicForService(service, characteristicAccGyrMg, (error, characteristic) => {
        if (error) {
          this.error(error.message)
          return
        }
        this.updateValue(characteristic.uuid, characteristic.value)
      })
    }
```

And this is updateValue:

```
updateValue(key, value) {
  //        const readebleData = base64.decode(value);
    this.setState({ values: { ...this.state.values, [key]: value } })
  }
```

I have try to use base64.decode(value) but the values that I receive are not number :/

Comment: That looks like a form of encoding...

Comment: @JackBashford Do you suggest something?

Comment: Well it's hard - where do those values come from?

Comment: It's not valid Base64 either.

Comment: @JackBashford These data come from a ble device, I have done the ScanAndConnect to device and the Monitoring ( with the function that i have post ) of Characteristics

Comment: But how are they encoded?

Comment: I know only that data are send with little-endian structure

Comment: @JackBashford I did some tests and I have obtain a number when I made  the convertion from "Text to Binary" and From "Binary to Decimal", it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently those values are hex encoded into base64. I could not find any documentation, but it's based on this Github issue: [monitorCharacteristicForService value is fragmented](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx/issues/442)

I used [this tool](https://cryptii.com/pipes/base64-to-hex) to convert your base64 to hex:

> **Accelerometer + Gyroscope:** "zLAi/wD/SpwiAOv/VwBnAML/xQE="
>
> `cc b0 22 ff 00 ff 4a 9c 22 00 eb ff 57 00 67 00 c2 ff c5 01`
>
> **Pressure:** "bgBvAHAAcQByAA="
>
> `6e 00 6f 00 70 00 71 00 72 00`
>
> **Battery:** "ChYKARoA"
>
> `0a 16 0a 01 1a 00`

Unfortunately, without knowing the specifications for this device, it is impossible to convert these hex values to numbers. The manufacturer could have chosen from an infinite number of methods to map numbers to hex values. You will either have to find the protocol documentation or reverse engineer it.

Here are [samples of how another BLE device converted numbers to hex](https://reverse-engineering-ble-devices.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol_description/00_protocol_description.html) (search for "notification consists"). You will find sections like this:

> The notification consists of 6 byte:
>
> ```
> byte 0: 02
> byte 1: 01
> byte 2: XY (see below)
> byte 3: valve open state in % (from 0x00 to 0x64)
> byte 4: undefined (battery level?)
> byte 5: (temperature * 2)
> ```

Comment: But I have try to convert to HEX to Decimal, and for example battery value give me: "10" when the real value should be 100

Comment: @MrRobinson: That is why "it is impossible to convert these hex values to numbers." There are an infinite number of  ways to encode 100% battery in hex. You assume it is a simple binary to decimal conversion, but there are many other ways. For example: fraction of 0xFF (255); fraction of 0x64 (100) like in example; ASCII characters '1', '0', '0'; etc...